# How to prompt save dialog to download file using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I have a directory in server that contains file now i am sending file name from client and getting the file from server till that part is working good, below is the response from server now once i receive response i want to prompt for user to download that file for that i am trying to create blob using Angularjs but its not prompting for user to save the file. Any idea ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.downloadFile = function(message){
        DitFactory.getFile(message).then(function(response){
            console.log('r',response);
            var blob = new Blob([ response ], { type : 'text/plain' });
            $scope.url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
            console.log($scope.url);
        });
    };
```

serverResponse.json

```
{"level":"info","message":"another-2fdas  message"}
```

server.js

```
app.get('/file', function (req, res) {
    var dir = './ditLogs';
    var root = path.resolve('./ditLogs');
    var fileName = req.query.file_name;
    var data;
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, items) {
        items.forEach(function(file){
            if(fileName === file){
                data = file;
                res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + data);
                res.sendFile(data, {root: root});
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: checkout https://github.com/rndme/download , which makes it `download($scope.url, "myfile.ext")`

Comment: i dont clearly understand how to implement this using angularjs from documentation

Comment: how we are using this wihtout adding as dependency to config or something

Comment: it's global, so.. you just use it. include it with a script tag.

Comment: ahh, i'm not an angular expert, but i know it's been used in angular projects, so it can't be hard. the base capability is also not something that's readily test-able, so i'm not sure how tightly you need to couple it.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using **express**, you can try below code in **server.js** file:

```
var file = 'path to your file';      
res.download(file,function(err){
    if(!err){
      console.log('prompted successfully');
      return;
  }
});
```